# Почему RecyclerView не правильно обновляет данные?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что методы `notifyItemRmoved()` и `notifyItemInserted()` не правильно обновляют данные после их вызова. Удаляю `item` из позиции 1, все нормально, удаляю потом из этой же позиции `item` который сместился из позиции 2 в 1, удаляется `item` ниже него, и все в таком духе.

Код метода адаптера, для удаления `items` за ранее:

```
public void removeItem(final Item item) {
    int position = this.items.indexOf(item);
    this.items.remove(position);
    super.notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```

Вызывал `notifyItemRangeChange()` после `notifyItemRemoved(position);` все равно не помогает. В общем `recycler` напрочь отказывается нормально работать с этими методами, проблему решает только `notifyDataSetChanged` но им не особо хочу пользоваться.

Из-за чего может быть такая проблема, может кто нибудь знает?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема может возникать если в адаптере `hasStableIds` возвращает `true`, а `getItemId` возвращает не уникальный id а просто текущую позицию элемента.

Comment: `getItemId` не переопределял и `hasStableIds  = false`

Comment: @Colibri Код выложьте